# Load remote content into div element using jQuery, SEO

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, iframe, seo

I want to Load remote content into div element using jQuery, i used this script which works great.

http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html

The contents are displayed but my problem is when i do a view-source in Browser the Javascript code is displayed instead of actual contents.

This wont help me with Search engine optimisation i think, can anyone suggest any alternative to display the actual contents in browser  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually any PHP or ASP scripting is not supported on my server so that i did is used

```
<iframe ="www.abc.com/test.php"><a href="www.abc.com/test.php">link</a></iframe>
```

Some SEO guy said that this will work because search engines will treat the url in IFRAME as a external link

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't help you in indexing content you could have to use sockets. (fsockopen in php)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm surprised the obvious answer isn't given, so for posterity I'll throw my two cents in.

You can view the contents of any dynamically created elements in any modern browser. IE and Chrome will both load up developer tools, which will show you the currently loaded DOM, by pressing F12. From there you can explore what's generated by Javascript.